# Problems on setting up Ubuntu as dual boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows, ext4

I have one SSD and one HDD on my PC. SSD runs Windows 7, i want to set up Ubuntu as dual boot on the HDD. I downloaded the WUBI.exe for 16.04 and installed it to my HDD. After first startup i got some errors like "root file system not defined" after it successfully booted to the main Ubuntu screen. I googled a bit and it seemed like (i was using both the HDD and SSD prior to that in Windows) my HDD was in NTFS and i needed to set up Ext4 first of all. So i downloaded Partition Wizard, and changed the HDD from NTFS to Ext4. Upon booting Ubuntu i get the error "error starting windows" for file "\ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.bmr". I can't boot Ubuntu, Windows 7 works fine, my HDD is not visible in Windows 7 anymore. How can i fix that?

I don't know alot about system settings, but the fact that my HDD is not visible under Windows should be ok, because Windows can't react Ext4. How can i repair my HDD tho, if i isn't visible under Windows anymore?

EDIT: I formatted the HDD again with partion wizard as EXT 4 and made a bootable USB stick with Ubuntu on it. After booting the stick to install Ubuntu on the HDD, it doesn't find the HDD in the installation menu and i can only select the SSD where my windows is installed. I don't want to partition the SSD. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it seems that you already reinstalled couple times to find out the answer why it is not working with dual-boot. I will answer with my own experience in which happened to me couple times as well, the difference is, i just had HDD to install on both OSes. My solutions are:

1. Trying to live-boot into your ubuntu
2. Install boot-repair, by typing below commands at your terminal

   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair

   sudo apt-get update -y

   sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair

3.When the program pops up, you can choose 'recommended-repair'

4.Restart the machine

Hopefully your OSes would be available to pick on GRUB menu.

[source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair]

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, it would be [preferable to include the essential parts of the answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Ahh, sorry for the ethical way. I will do it better next time. Thank you.

Comment: It is possible for you to do better now.  There is an edit link just below the post.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. I can't even finish step 1. When i can choose between booting up Windows7 or Ubuntu, if i choose Ubuntu, it immediately crashes, as described in my post. If i boot up from my USB stick with ubuntu on it, i can choose between installing Ubuntu and Starting Ubuntu without installing. It then stops at a blank black screen and i can't do anything other than restarting.